# why does vba want me to use an assignment for a function/sub call?

Tags: function, vba

Im trying to create a simple log function in my Excel VBA project.

I want to pass the current procedure name and a string

the log function looks currently like this:

```
Public Sub log(procName As String, message As String)
   dolog (procName & ": " & message)
End Sub
```

I am trying to call it like this:

```
Dim C_PROC_NAME As String
C_PROC_NAME = "autoSave"
log(C_PROC_NAME, "test")
```

That does not work, it excpects me to do it like this:

```
test = log(C_PROC_NAME, "test")
```

And initializing the C_PROC_NAME like this does *NOT* work as well:

```
DIM C_PROC_NAME As String = "autoSave"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to call a sub with parens, you need to place a `Call` keyword in front:

```
Dim C_PROC_NAME As String
C_PROC_NAME = "autoSave"
Call log(C_PROC_NAME, "test")
```

Or you can call it without parens:

```
Dim C_PROC_NAME As String
C_PROC_NAME = "autoSave"
log C_PROC_NAME, "test"
```